# Python string search efficiency

Tags: python, performance

For very large strings (spanning multiple lines) is it faster to use Python's built-in string search or to split the large string (perhaps on `\n`) and iteratively search the smaller strings?

E.g., for very large strings:

```
for l in get_mother_of_all_strings().split('\n'):
 if 'target' in l:
   return True
return False
```

or

```
return 'target' in get_mother_of_all_strings()
```

Comment: `get_mother_of_all_strings` is such a funny name for a function haha'

Comment: There's probably a Boyer-Moore or similar algorithm under the covers, which just *loves* going through big data. Use the full string.

Comment: This is easy to test by yourself, generate a very long string that doesn't contain the string you're looking for (worst case scenario) like `'a\n' * 100000000` and compare the execution times.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<del>Probably</del> Certainly the second, I don't see any difference in doing a search in a big string or many in small strings. You may skip some chars thanks to the shorter lines, but the split operation has its costs too (searching for `\n`, creating n different strings, creating the list) and the loop is done in python.

The string `__contain__` method is implemented in C and so noticeably faster.

Also consider that the second method aborts as soon as the first match is found, but the first one *splits* all the string before even starting to search inside it.

This is rapidly proven with a simple benchmark:

```
import timeit

prepare = """
with open('bible.txt') as fh:
    text = fh.read()
"""

presplit_prepare = """
with open('bible.txt') as fh:
    text = fh.read()
lines = text.split('\\n')
"""

longsearch = """
'hello' in text
"""

splitsearch = """
for line in text.split('\\n'):
    if 'hello' in line:
        break
"""

presplitsearch = """
for line in lines:
    if 'hello' in line:
        break
"""


benchmark = timeit.Timer(longsearch, prepare)
print "IN on big string takes:", benchmark.timeit(1000), "seconds"

benchmark = timeit.Timer(splitsearch, prepare)
print "IN on splitted string takes:", benchmark.timeit(1000), "seconds"

benchmark = timeit.Timer(presplitsearch, presplit_prepare)
print "IN on pre-splitted string takes:", benchmark.timeit(1000), "seconds"
```

The result is:

```
IN on big string takes: 4.27126097679 seconds
IN on splitted string takes: 35.9622690678 seconds
IN on pre-splitted string takes: 11.815297842 seconds
```

The bible.txt file actually *is* the bible, I found it here: http://patriot.net/~bmcgin/kjvpage.html (text version)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only matching once to see if the substring is in the string at all, then both methods are about the same, and you get more overhead for splitting it into separate line by line searches; so the large string search is a bit faster.

If you have to do multiple matches, then I would tokenize the string and stuff them into a dictionary or set and store it in memory.

```
s = 'SOME REALLY LONG STRING'
tokens = set(s.split())
return substring in tokens
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import timeit

a = #a really long string with multiple lines and target near the end

timeit.timeit(stmt='["target" in x for x in a.split("\\n")]', setup='a = """%s"""'%a)
23.499058284211792
timeit.timeit(stmt='"target" in a', setup='a = """%s"""'%a)
5.2557157624293325
```

So the large string is MUCH faster to search through than a split list of smaller ones.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is a lot faster, here are some measurement data:

```
def get_mother_of_all_strings():
    return "abcdefg\nhijklmnopqr\nstuvwxyz\naatargetbb"

first: 2.00
second: 0.26
```

Answer (score 0):

for loop in python is slow, and split a large string is also slow. so search the large string is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The second way is faster, the slitting adds one more O(n) iteration of searching and delimiting, the alocating memory for each sublist, then *close to* **O(n^2)** to iter each sublist and search a string in them. while just **O(n)** to search the bigger string.

Comment: Your complexity arguments are fallacious... it takes more O(n) iterations, but it never becomes an O(n^2) operation because the initial data set is the same.

Comment: @GaretJax, I see, but anyway, the conclusion is true.